# Azure Vault and VM Disk Encryption 'Access Denied'

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to encrypt a VM using an Azure Vault i have created. I have created an app registration and added it to an access policy.

This access policy has full privileges to the vault.

I have then run the following powershell command to encrypt the VM:

```
$RGName = “XXXX"
$VMName = “XXXX"
$AADClientID = "7704d32e-acc1-4258-89b9-743f7e28d6f4”
$AADClientSecret = "XXXX”
$VaultName= “XXXX"
$KeyVault = Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $VaultName -ResourceGroupName $RGName
$DiskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl = $KeyVault.VaultUri 
$KeyVaultResourceId = $KeyVault.ResourceId 
Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension -ResourceGroupName $RGName -VMName $VMName -AadClientID $AADClientID -AadClientSecret $AADClientSecret -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl $DiskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultId $KeyVaultResourceId
```

I then get the following error:

```
Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'AzureDiskEncryption'. Error message: "Failed to configure bitlocker as expected.
Exception: Access denied, InnerException: , stack trace:    at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.UploadBekToKeyVault(EncryptableVolume vol, String protectorId, Boolean saveKeyToBekVolume)
   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.GenerateAndUploadProtectorForVolume(EncryptableVolume vol, Boolean saveKeyToBekVolume)
   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.GenerateAndUploadOsVolumeProtector()
   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.EnableEncryption()
   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.HandleEncryptionOperations()
   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.OnEnable()".'
ErrorCode: VMExtensionProvisioningError
ErrorMessage: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'AzureDiskEncryption'. Error message: "Failed to configure bitlocker as expected. Exception: Access denied, InnerException: , stack trace:    at
Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.UploadBekToKeyVault(EncryptableVolume vol, String protectorId, Boolean saveKeyToBekVolume)
   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.GenerateAndUploadProtectorForVolume(EncryptableVolume vol, Boolean saveKeyToBekVolume)
   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.GenerateAndUploadOsVolumeProtector()
   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.EnableEncryption()
   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.HandleEncryptionOperations()
   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.OnEnable()".
StartTime: 2/4/2018 7:14:08 PM
EndTime: 2/4/2018 7:14:14 PM
OperationID: bbeb1676-a4a1-4473-8051-038f34c2ac69
Status: Failed
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension -ResourceGroupName $RGName -VMNa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmVMDiskEncryptionExtension], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Extension.AzureDiskEncryption.SetAzureDiskEncryptionExtensionCommand
```

Below is the settings for the key vault

```
Vault Name                       : XXXX
Resource Group Name              : XXXX
Location                         : uksouth
Resource ID                      : /subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/XXXX/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/XXXX
Vault URI                        : https://XXXX.vault.azure.net/
Tenant ID                        : XXXX
SKU                              : Standard
Enabled For Deployment?          : True
Enabled For Template Deployment? : True
Enabled For Disk Encryption?     : True
Soft Delete Enabled?             :
Access Policies                  :
                                   Tenant ID                                  : XXXX
                                   Object ID                                  : 5dc9a404-6b67-4529-a722-2d941b439352
                                   Application ID                             : 7704d32e-acc1-4258-89b9-743f7e28d6f4
                                   Display Name                               :
                                   Permissions to Keys                        : Encrypt, Decrypt, WrapKey, UnwrapKey, Sign, Verify, Get, List, Create, Update, Import, Delete, Backup, Restore
                                   Permissions to Secrets                     : Get, List, Set, Delete
                                   Permissions to Certificates                : Get, List, Delete, Create, Import, Update, ManageContacts, GetIssuers, ListIssuers, SetIssuers, DeleteIssuers, ManageIssuers, Recover, Purge
                                   Permissions to (Key Vault Managed) Storage :
```

I have checked all privileges and everything seems to be fine. Any suggestions on what the error might be or how i could debug it would be very helpful.

Comment: You should never see a stack trace in Powershell - enter a bug here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues and then open a support request with Azure Support in the portal.

Comment: I suggest you could check log in `C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Security.AzureDiskEncryption\1.1.0.4`

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the KV for disk encryption.

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $keyVaultName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName –EnabledForDiskEncryption
```

> The Azure platform needs access to the encryption keys or secrets in
>   your key vault to make them available to the virtual machine when it
>   boots and decrypts the virtual machine OS volume. To grant permissions
>   to Azure platform, set the EnabledForDiskEncryption property in the
>   key vault.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption#prerequisites

Comment: Thank you for the reply. These are already enabled. I have edited my original post to show all of the permissions.

Comment: try with a fresh vm, try with `-skipVmBackup` if its a managed disk vm. are you using a supported image?

Comment: I have enabled the `Azure Disk Encryption for volume encryption` permission in my KeyVault instance and it's not working.

Comment: you should raise a new question @FelipeCruz